# There exist or there exists

Tags: grammar, verbs

Which one is correct?

1. Based on assumption C, there  exists an object A and two other objects D and E.
2. Based on assumption C, there  exist an object A and two other objects D and E.

Comment: What do you think, and why?

Comment: The second one, because of subject verb agreement?

Comment: So what’s the issue?

Comment: Substitute "is/are"  for "exists/exist".